# Effectively using all CPU cores while exporting a sequence of plots

Tags: graphics, export, parallelization

In Wolfram Mathematica 12.3.1 on macOS I use

```
Do[Export i-th plot to PNG file,{i,LargeNumber}]
```

to generate a sequence of plots. This works well, but I noticed that CPU usage is about 60% idle.

If I use `ParallelDo`, the number goes does to about 45%. This is a bit better but leaves me wondering whether I can optimise further.

Edit: It looks like storing several images in RAM first and then writing out a batch of images at once does not really have much of an effect.

Comment: **1** What is your OS **2** Is your OS otherwise busy  **3** Have you changed some config to assume that the OS will give you more CPU usage for your Mathematica process **4** Is this process perhaps being limited by the hard drive?

Comment: Thanks! 1) macos 10.15.7 2) No 3) Not that that I am aware of. 4) Not sure.

Comment: I once had the same problem. I don't think that this is possible because PNG export somehow involves the FrontEnd.

Comment: I also believe PNG export (and likely exports for all image formats that require Mathematica to rasterise something) is done via the frontend, which is not parallelizable in the same sense as code that does not involve the frontend.

Comment: Hm, everything is done using WolframScript so I am not sure about the frontend issue. In any case, using `ParallelDo` instead of `Do` already made my export roughly 50% faster.